# Markdown italics with underscores look good in preview but not in answer

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown, markdown-preview

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108612/method-with-same-name-and-different-parameters-in-ruby/1108714#1108714) of mine has some italicized words containing underscores in the first line.
These look good in the preview, but in the answer they appear non-italicized with surrounding asterisks.

Is this a known bug, and is there a workaround?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Workaround - write the italics tag yourself. For example:

```
Use <i>attr_accessor</i> to add attributes
```

produces:

Use *attr_accessor* to add attributes

Ugly, but it works.

As for whether it's a known bug - it's known now ;) (Things like this are fundamentally tricky for markdown, unfortunately.)

Comment: Alternatively, escape the underscore: `*this\_works as well*`: *this\_works as well*

Comment: *Ugly?* **UGLY?!?!?!** HTML is beautiful.

Answer (score 7):

The server-side markdown parser does not like mixing _ and *.

Don't cross the streams!

Comment: In that case, what happens when I do this: *_*_*_*_*_*_*