# Markdown bug in preview pane (incorrect italicization)

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, markdown

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Markdown italics with underscores look good in preview but not in answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4202/markdown-italics-with-underscores-look-good-in-preview-but-not-in-answer)

I just ran into an interesting markdown bug with previews that I thought I'd throw out there in case it's new.

The post in question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609467/in-perl-is-there-a-built-in-way-to-compare-two-arrays-for-equality/1609602#1609602).  The text looks fine in the "normal" view, but in the preview pane ([while editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1609602/edit)) it looks like this:

> There's [Test::More](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Test::More)'s eq*deeply() function, which will also display exactly where the structures differ, or [Test::Deep](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Test::Deep)'s eq*deeply(), which doesn't require a test harness (and just returns true or false).

Somehow the underscore characters are being interpreted as start italics/end italics.

EDIT: I can't seem to reproduce the appearance here. In the preview pane here on meta it looks like it does in the original post, but after posting, it comes out wrong (the asterisks are visible).  Clearly it's not possible to demonstrate a bug in markdown *using* markdown :)

Comment: deferred to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1227/preview-should-match-the-posted-view  , but the link isn't exactly a dupe.  I'll close too if someone gives a better link.

Comment: Found another dupe here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4202/markdown-italics-with-underscores-look-good-in-preview-but-not-in-answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Known bug.  Intra-word emphasis are part of the markdown spec, but they're disabled here as they cause problems in code snippets.

The bug is that the preview doesn't handle this departure properly, even though it will be correct (for the SO-modified version of "correct") when it's posted.  But that's old news:
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1227/preview-should-match-the-posted-view