# Small inconsistency between HTML Preview and serverside markdown

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown

When [answering this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46642/what-markdown-is-allowed-in-comments/46643#46643), I wanted to simulate the comment limitation that you can't have ***bold italics***, as it renders as ***only bold*** on comments, but I realized that on the HTML preview it renders as ***only italics***, while on the question itself it renders correctly.

This seems to invert both cases.

Of course, this is quite an edge case, not many will go around using `\***only bold**\*` or `**\*only italics\***`, but I can imagine cases where this would be a problem.

<sub>You can edit this question to see it</sub>

Comment: This sounds familiar.

Comment: @random: all markdown errors sound familiar. You have only so much different combinations of syntax.

Comment: I can't believe you only just now taxonomized the [edge-case] tag. Seems like this belongs on most bug reports on Meta.

Comment: Pick: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1227/preview-should-match-the-posted-view http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4202/markdown-italics-with-underscores-look-good-in-preview-but-not-in-answer http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26961/markdown-bug-in-preview-pane-incorrect-italicization

Comment: @balpha: cést la vie.

Comment: @random: you linked twice to the same one. I guess you wan't me to pick http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4202. Also, this is quite specific. If closed, I'm not sure if Jeff will even glance at it.

Comment: @balpha: There was already a `[corner-case]` tag. Maybe we should keep bugging Jeff for [tag synonyms](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2779/could-the-tagging-system-be-enhanced-to-support-tag-synonyms)?

Comment: Duped dupes, but gave you another to have a look over, this thing is hairy.

Comment: @Jon, by completely [unscientific](http://www.google.com/search?q=edge+case) [methods](http://www.google.com/search?q=corner+case) I've determined that [edge case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_case) is more commonly used than [corner case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corner_case), although they don't mean exactly the same.

Comment: @json: Okay. Is this an edge case or a corner case? :D

Comment: Well, a corner case covers an even more specific detail than an edge case -- it's an edge case of an edge case, if you will.  This particular issue is about the inconsistency between the ***preview*** of the combination of two markup elements and the display of said combination.  Totally a corner case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't ask me which particular change fixed this, but preview and final version are identical now. As a side note, bold italics in comments [also work now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/79981/115866).