# Italics (asterisk) not possible when text contains an underscore

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Markdown italics with underscores look good in preview but not in answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4202/markdown-italics-with-underscores-look-good-in-preview-but-not-in-answer)

> <strike>**Possible Duplicate:**
>
>   [Preview should match the posted view](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1227/preview-should-match-the-posted-view)</strike>

Original q:

> *"In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745683/button-not-picking-up-c-code-behind-event-what-did-i-do-wrong/1745702#1745702), I added a cursive
>   paragraph, which I've done more often.
>   But now it doesn't work anymore. I
>   tried preceding it with other text,
>   played with `*` and `_`, but to no
>   avail. Has there been a new submission
>   of Mardown? I haven't seen this
>   behavior before.*
>
> *The code looks good in preview (but I know preview is using JS)."*

While experimenting further, I found out that *using an underscore in cursive text will ignore the asterisk*.

*An example_here we go wrong*

*EDIT: see history of referenced question and see this [possible duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4202/markdown-italics-with-underscores-look-good-in-preview-but-not-in-answer) (sorry, I can't mark it myself for duplicates).*

*EDIT: workaround: escape the underscore with a backslash. Ugly, but you can use it until this bug is fixed.*

Comment: cursive text, as in profanity laden or handwritten?

Comment: handwritten with a goose-quill! (sorry, not native, "cursief" is Dutch and means italics, I tend to mix them up).

Comment: @Abel: don't worry, spanish adn portuguese speakers understood you too :) here, have a cookie

Comment: lekker! crunchy!

Comment: I think you mean _italic text_.

Comment: deferred to dupe

Comment: Thanks, Joel, I found another dupe (was already in the original text) and a workaround (not mentioned in the other threads).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the _ in the word `Page_Load()`.  Intra-word emphasis confuse the markdown renderer.  It's a known issue:
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1227/preview-should-match-the-posted-view

Comment: Technically, when "inside" a markdown section, you should consider matching the pairs (starting with **`*`** must have a matching asterisk and cannot end with **`_`**, but *can* be interspersed with underscores). Using regexes in .NET, this is trivial to solve with balancing expressions. .NET is the only language supporting that, which makes it rather unknown, but it would easily fix many such errors currently troubling your users.