# Why do italics sometimes work and sometimes do not work?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design

This is definitely the most irritating aspect of an otherwise excellent service:

As of **6/4/14:**

**No Italics:**

*app/controllers/users_controller.rb*

**Italics:**

*app/models/user.rb*

Why? **Because there's an underscore** in the first path? This is a bug, right?

Comment: **+1** *Your* formatting *is* **excellent**.

Comment: @BlueIce http://www.troll.me/images/futurama-fry/cant-tell-if-sarcasm.jpg

Comment: Yep, it's the underscore. You'd have to escape it. Known issue: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30016/italics-asterisk-not-possible-when-text-contains-an-underscore

Comment: @Bart Ah, I feel I should know better! Thanks for that tip, I'll shall use it till the end of my days (or when SE fix this). Definitely think they should fix this though, especially for the non-programming SE sites.

Comment: It's not them who have to fix this though iirc. It's an external library that, I think, you could even fix. :)

Comment: As of ... June 2014? [ISO please](https://xkcd.com/1179/). @Bart It's not really *external*; it's primarily developed by SE staff, using open source code. [PageDown and Markdown Sharp](https://code.google.com/p/pagedown/wiki/PageDown).

Comment: @cheapeffectivedietpills British time my colonial companion