# Bug: Italic text not working properly

Tags: support, status-completed, markdown, markdown-preview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Markdown italics with underscores look good in preview but not in answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4202/markdown-italics-with-underscores-look-good-in-preview-but-not-in-answer)

Example: [Ignore "initialization from incompatible pointer type" warnings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763616/ignore-initialization-from-incompatible-pointer-type-warnings)

Comment: *Works!* Could you be a little bit more informative?

Comment: I assume you're referring to *Hardware_MouseDrivers_GPM_Methods*? That's a dupe, a known issue that with italicizing terms with underscores. I'll go in and fix that in the original post for you. We really can't do anything about this, but there is a workaround: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4202/a-classic

Comment: Heh, check that out, it works in comments. :)

Comment: Curse you Smithers! A slow moving attempt at Taxonimist is thwarted!

Comment: You can't trick the system that easy, random! Be innovative!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you want italic there; I converted it to a code block using backticks:

```
`code_block`
```