# Markdown to italicize Windows registry key

Tags: bug, markdown

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Markdown italics with underscores look good in preview but not in answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4202/markdown-italics-with-underscores-look-good-in-preview-but-not-in-answer)

When I try use Markdown to italicize this Windows Registry key, I can't seem to make it work...

*HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SharedAccess\Parameters\FirewallPolicy\FirewallRules*

However, I can make the same text bold...

**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SharedAccess\Parameters\FirewallPolicy\FirewallRules**

Is this expected behavior?  I know I could wrap it in HTML `<i>` tags; however, I am curious why Markdown isn't handling this case...

Comment: Escape the underscores inside the text

Comment: hmm why is the duplicate [status-completed] and not by-design or wont-fix?