# Markdown tables with unmatched backtick \` should either not show as a table in preview or show correctly after preview

Tags: bug, markdown, markdown-preview, tables

I spotted a discrepancy between Markdown preview and posted questions. This discrepancy also holds for answers.

When using unmatched backticks ` inside a table cell, like in following source:

```
|header1|header2|
|--|--|
|umatched`|backtick|
|`matched`|backticks|
```

then in Preview it is shown correctly like this:

| header1 | header2 |
| --- | --- |
| umatched` | backtick |
| `matched` | backticks |

But outside of preview, in questions and answers, it is only shown as the following garbled text:

|header1|header2|
|--|--|
|umatched`|backtick| |`matched`|backticks|

I had to escape the first backtick in first table above to show it as a table.

I spotted that problem in https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/71021836/3

Preview of table has [other](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/404376/2987828) [problems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/4202/242736), so I guess my bug is a bug in the same part of SE's source code.

Comment: Is it the intended formatting here in this post after "garbled text" (several lines in the Markdown source here in this post)?

Comment: This is because SE uses different renders for preview and actual posts. This issue is an "edge case" so may not get corrected. See: [Link renders differently on client and server side when preceded by a special character](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/349717/771581)

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum right, I thought "garbled text" was a good descriptor. I welcome any suggestion of a better wording than "garbled text".

Comment: @BigBrother but that let several people post garbled answers and questions, see what I linked in my question. Is that accepted ?